# JQuery Datepicker do not use the defined format

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I have a weird situation (or at least it is to me :-)
I'm working on a MVC 4 application using `C#`.

Having 2 input fields using JQuery DatePicker setup like this:

```
<div class="spacing float-left">
    @Html.Label("Start dato", new { @class = "editor-label" })
    @Html.TextBox("StartdatoInput", "", new { @class = "gray-border-1 layer-1" })
</div>

<div class="spacing float-left">
    @Html.Label("Slut dato", new { @class = "editor-label" })
    @Html.TextBox("SlutdatoInput", "", new { @class = "gray-border-1 layer-1" })
</div>
```

Definition of the pickeropts are:

```
function CalendarEntries()
{
    var pickerOpts = {
        closeText: "Afslut",
        currentText: "i dag",
        nextText: "næste",
        prevText: "forrige",
        monthNames: ["Januar", "Februar", "Marts", "April", "Maj", "Juni",
        "Juli", "August", "September", "Oktober", "November", "December"],
        monthNamesShort: ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "Maj", "Jun", "Jul",
        "Aug", "Sep", "Okt", "Nov", "Dec"],
        dayNames: ["Mandag", "Tirsdag", "Onsdag", "Torsdag", "Fredag",
        "Lørdag", "Søndag"],
        dayNamesShort: ["Søn", "Man", "Tir", "Ons", "Tor", "Fre", "Lør"],
        dayNamesMin: ["Sø", "Ma", "Ti", "On", "To", "Fr", "Lø"],
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
        firstDay: 1,
        isRTL: false,
        showButtonPanel: true
    };


    $("#StartdatoInput").datepicker(pickerOpts);
    $("#SlutdatoInput").datepicker(pickerOpts);



    jQuery.extend(jQuery.datepicker, { _checkOffset: function (inst, offset, isFixed) 
    {     offset.top = offset.top; offset.left = offset.left - 220; return offset; } });

}
```

And initializing as this:

```
    $("#StartdatoInput").datepicker(pickerOpts);
    $("#SlutdatoInput").datepicker(pickerOpts);
```

My expectation would be that both of the input fields would use the `dd/mm/yy` format, but `StartdatoInput` is using the default format (mm/dd/yy)

Any ideas of what is wrong?

Comment: It's working fine check here http://jsfiddle.net/7tLM9/1/

Comment: Silly me :-) I had another function who formatted the input field. Above was working quite OK as Runcorn stated. Thanks.

Comment: Such mistakes happens sometime. Glad you figured it out on your own. :D